# Блок с фиксированной высотой по центру между шапкой и футером

Tags: html, css, css3

есть шапка:

```
.header{ height: 45px; }
```

и есть футер, прижатый к низу страницы:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 45px;
}
```

и есть центральный блок с фиксированной высотой:

```
.center{
    height: 350px;
}
```

надо сделать так, что бы .center всегда был вертикально по центру между .header и .footer. Т.е. если я буду уменьшать размер окна браузера по высоте, то .center все равно должен автоматически выравниваться по вертикально по центру. Естественно, если буду сильно сжимать окно браузера, то футер залезет на .center - так и задумано.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ - хорошая статья про центрирование

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `margin: 0 auto;` но при этом так же вставить ширину блока т.е

```
.center{
    height: 350px;
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: я это сразу пробовал. Он прилагает к шапке, а нужно, в независимости он размера экрана, что бы  .center был точно посередине между шапкой и футером.

Comment: значит вам надо позиционировать абсолютно ваш центр, обновлю ответ

Answer (score 0):

Видоизменил ответ, раскрасил элементы для наглядности.

```
.header{ height: 45px; background:#CCC}

.center{
    height: 350px; display:block; background:green;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 45px;
   background:#F00;
  width:100%;
}

<div class="header">Header</div>


<div class="centered">
  <div class="center">Just some text</div>
</div>


<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/6cVBW44Sw4#

Comment: А если высота футера не равна высоте шапки, например 300px. Тогда мой центр с высотой 200px уже не будет в центре по вертикале между футером и шапкой.

Comment: Видоизменил ответ, раскрасил элементы для наглядности.
Выравнивание происходит в div МЕЖДУ хедером и футером.

Answer (score 0):

Добавим центральный контейнер `.container` между футером и хедером с высотой равной `100vh`, вычтем из этой величины высоту хедера и футера `height: calc(100vh - 45px - 45px)` и добавим ему `display: flex`, чтобы можно было по-быстрому центрировать блок внутри. Добавим блоку `.center` свойство `margin: auto`, чтобы центрировать по вертикали и горизонтали.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
}

.center {
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100vh - 45px - 45px); /* от полной высоты окна вычитаем высоту футера и хедера */
  min-height: 350px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  header
</div>
<div class=container>
  <div class=center>
    Hello, I'm at center of this page
  </div>
</div>
<div class=footer>
  footer
</div>
```