# Равномерное поднятие и опускание блоков по всей высоте страницы не зависимо от размера экрана

Tags: html, jquery, css

Эта задача является продолжением моей работы над тремя блоками.
[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637355/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637485/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) начало моей работы. Все проблемы в предыдущих вопросах уже решены и спасибо Вам большое. Внизу код уже конечного результата.

***Описание того, что уже есть:***

Есть три блока: шапка - меньше всего информативный блок и ним можно жертвовать, центр - блок важен, но тоже жертвую и футер - самый информативный блок и по необходимости он закрывает все остальные. Шапка прижата вверху страницы, футер прижат к низу. При развернутом окне браузера цент будет всегда находится посередине между футером и шапкой. Если сузить окно браузера, то по степени информативности блоки будут закрывать один одного плавно и красиво. Футер будет налазить на центр, при этом центр будет от него "убегать", закрывая собой шапку, но в итоге футер закроет все, т.к. он самый важный. Теперь на футере появились кнопки вверх и вниз, которые поднимают/опускают его. При этом центр "старается" все равно оставаться в центре между шапкой и футером. С поднятием футера все выше, центр "убегает" от него, закрывая собой шапку, но футер продолжает подыматься, закрывая собой цент. Есть поднять 3-4 раза, а потом опустить 3-4 раза, то все выглядит очень красиво и так как я хотел. Но если поднимать в самый вверх, появляются проблемы.

***Постановка этой задачи:***

Первая проблема в том, что центр и футер при полном своем поднятии должны прижаться к верху окна браузера, но они немного прячутся, что не очень красиво.

Вторая проблема, когда после полного поднятия начинать опускать футер, то центр уже не "станет на свое место".

3-я проблема. Даже если поднять футер на 3-4 раза, а потом изменить высоту окна браузера и опустить/поднять, то центр, тоже уже "не станет на место".

Уверен, что должно быть правильное решение задачи. Если я хочу "заоблачного" и решения нет, тогда подскажите, как наиболее эстетично решить мои проблемы. Заранее благодарен.

```js
$('#footer').on('click', '#up_footer', function() {
  var height = $("#footer").height() + 30;
  if(height >= $("body").outerHeight()) return;
  else{
   $("#footer").animate({'height': height});
   if($(".center").outerHeight() >= $("body").outerHeight() + 15) return;
   else $(".center").animate({'padding-bottom': parseInt($(".center").css("padding-bottom")) + 15});
  }
    });
 
 $('#footer').on('click', '#down_footer', function() {
  var height = $("#footer").height() - 30;
  if(height < 100) return;
  else{
   $("#footer").animate({'height': height});
   $(".center").animate({'padding-bottom': parseInt($(".center").css("padding-bottom")) - 15});
  }
    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
.wrapper {
  background-color: #F8E5DB;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6F6748;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 1px #9b9b9b;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 207px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  background-color: #402000;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 3px 0px #9b9b9b;
  border-top: 1px solid #6F6748;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #606060;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-family: Arial, sens-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

#up_footer  { background: url("../img/up.png");  }
#down_footer { background: url("../img/down.png");  }

#up_footer,
#down_footer{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ce0000; 
  color: #efffbf;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 280px);
  padding-bottom: 230px;
}

.wrap_border_center{
 height: 304px;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #9b9b9b;
 border: 5px solid #402000;
 border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #FFCA95;
}

.centered-middle{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

@media (max-height: 550px) {
  .center {
    height: calc(100% - 243px);
    padding-bottom: 213px;
  }
  .footer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 477px) {
  .center {
    height: calc(100% - 230px);
    padding-bottom: 230px;
  }
  .footer {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>ШАПКА</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="center">
    <table class="centered-middle">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td>
          <div class="wrap_border_center">
            центр
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" id="footer">
    <div class="updown">
   <div id="down_footer" title="Опустить вних">Опустить вних</div>
   <div id="up_footer" title="Поднять вверх">Поднять вверх</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>информация</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var overIncrement = 0; // для ловли избытка в смещении, когда .center уже не сдвигается выше

$('#footer').on('click', '#up_footer', function() {
  var height = $("#footer").height() + 30;
  var bodyHeight = $("body").outerHeight();

  if(height < bodyHeight) {
    var differentH = bodyHeight - $(".center").outerHeight();
    if(differentH > 0) {
      var resultPadding = 0;
      differentH >= 15 ? resultPadding = 15 : resultPadding = differentH; // Проверяем, не больше ли 15 нужный отступ
      $(".center").css('padding-bottom', parseInt($('.center').css('padding-bottom')) + resultPadding);
    } else {
      overIncrement++;
    }

    $("#footer").css('height', height);
  }
});
  
$('#footer').on('click', '#down_footer', function() {
  var height = $("#footer").height() - 30;
  if(height >= 100) {
    if(overIncrement === 0) {
      $(".center").css('padding-bottom', parseInt($(".center").css("padding-bottom")) - 15);
    } else {
      overIncrement--;
    }
    $("#footer").css('height', height);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
.wrapper {
  background-color: #F8E5DB;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6F6748;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 1px #9b9b9b;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 207px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  background-color: #402000;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 3px 0px #9b9b9b;
  border-top: 1px solid #6F6748;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #606060;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-family: Arial, sens-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

#up_footer    { background: url("../img/up.png");   }
#down_footer  { background: url("../img/down.png");   }

#up_footer,
#down_footer{
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ce0000; 
  color: #efffbf;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 300px);
  padding-bottom: 230px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.wrap_border_center{
  height: 304px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #9b9b9b;
  border: 5px solid #402000;
  border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #FFCA95;
}

.centered-middle{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-height: 550px) {
  .center {
    height: calc(100% - 243px);
    padding-bottom: 213px;
  }
  .footer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 477px) {
  .center {
    height: calc(100% - 230px);
    padding-bottom: 230px;
  }
  .footer {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>ШАПКА</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="center">
    <table class="centered-middle">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td>
          <div class="wrap_border_center">
            центр
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" id="footer">
    <div class="updown">
   <div id="down_footer" title="Опустить вних">Опустить вних</div>
   <div id="up_footer" title="Поднять вверх">Поднять вверх</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>информация</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Здесь не нужно использовать .animate() - это излишество. Просто добавляем transition: all .3s ease; к #footer и .center , и меняем animate() на css(). То, что можно сделать средствами css - лучше делать им.

1-ая проблема: .center изменил с 280px на 300px, проблема была в том, что у тебя в классе .centered-middle была высота 100% (изменил на auto). Здесь у тебя есть таблица, которая была "не прижата" к самому верху (к бордеру) и оставалось свободное место из-за calc(100% - px).
Так же переписал проверку на отступ (см комментарии в коде).

2-ая проблема: добавил overIncrement, что бы отлавливать избыточный сдвиг. (возможны погрешности на 2-3 пикселя, т.к. последний сдвиг может быть меньше 15)

3-я проблема: тебе поможет функция .resize() на window. Здесь очень много хардкода с вычислением высоты через css и можно повязнуть на несколько часов, так что все в твоих руках :)

P.S. Переписал if(!cond) {return;} else {...} на if(cond) {...}, т.к. это лишние строки кода, которые ухудшают читаемость и не используются.
Задача индивидуальна и вряд ли поможет кому-то еще. Но надеюсь, что тебе помог мой ответ.

Comment: не идеал, но все же стало намного лучше чем было, за что Вам огромное спасибо. Спасибо, что указали на погрешности. Мне еще многому стоит учится.